# jackson ObjectMapper is adding an illegal character to base64 img string field on writeValueAsString

Tags: android, base64, jackson2

I am trying to send an object with an image converted to a `base64` string, but when I convert that `object` to a `json` string to send it,  multiple `"\n"` characters are added to that string which makes it invalid when it reaches the server.

Converting bitmap to a valid `base64` (I checked if its valid)

```
     ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
     base64Str =  Base64.encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray(), 
     Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Creating the request and setting the `base64` string to be sent to the backed

```
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     Request = new Request();
     payload.setData(base64);
```

on writeValueAsString a `"/n"` is added at the end of the `base64` value which makes it invalid

```
      String reqBody = "";
      try {
          reqBody = mapper.writeValueAsString(payload);
      } 
      catch (Exception ex) {
            }
```

a part of the valid base 64 before converting to json

```
"Kz7cruI+8gLNZRgnnKihQFDNt42sGaQlWMhVt2fLG9Q20NwpIx/
J0OWdOM4cso8tlZ3skldNWau0mmt7XT1P2/mcH
aWk15dFJrm+53Xndu7aP/9k="
```

a part of the valid base 64 after converting to json (notice the inclusion of '\n')

```
"Kz7cruI+8gLNZ\nRgnnKihQFDNt42sGaQlWMhVt2fLG9Q20NwpIx
/J0OWdOM4cso8tlZ3skldNWau0mmt7XT1P2/mcH\naWk15dFJrm+53Xndu7aP/9k=\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the new line character "\n" is added on encodeToString by default, to add a wrap effect. Just replace Base64.DEFAULT with  Base64.NO_WRAP to remove it in the encoded string.